# Add a custom button when image click in visual editor wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, image, visual-editor

I would like to add an 'addclass' button who appears when image is clicked in visual editor of wordpress.

Currently, this menu appears :

[image: MCE MENU]

When my button will be click, the class '.w50' will be add to my image.
Lot of plugins exist about add buttons to the wordpress editor but nothing about this type of menu.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: And what have you tried yourself in order to achieve this?

Comment: @Epodax I tried to modifie this file myself : wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpeditimage/plugin.js 
But my skills in PHP are limited. 

I tried to force to replace image of the current icon and Class "alignleft" by "w50" with Jquery too.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a own tool in wp_editor . so please see below code

```
$args = array(
    'tinymce' => true,
    'teeny' => true,
);
wp_editor( $Value, $Name, $args );

add_filter( 'teeny_mce_buttons', 'my_editor_buttons', 10, 2 );
function my_editor_buttons( $buttons, $editor_id ) {
    return array( 'formatselect', 'bold', 'italic' );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to creat a new editor, just add custom specific button on the existing editor